# WPF datagrid column color dynamic binding on a single Value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, background

I have a datagrid and would like to have one of the columns' background color dynamically linked to a single value from the background code.  I don't want to add a list of value to my ObservableCollection for the datagrid for binding the background color since I only need one color for an entire column (the color needs to change based on a value not related to the datagrid datacontext).

I've looked around, it seemed that most of the discussion is about change the cell background color based on the value displayed.

Thank you.

Here is my xmal code for the datagrid column....

```
   <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fleet" Width = "100*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Fleet,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="FleetDataGridCell_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                            <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="FleetDataGridCell_KeyDown" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding}"/>

                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Where is the background color sitting? In a ViewModel, Code-Behind?
Your approach with a cellstyle look right and you don't have to put the color in the ObservableCollection.

Comment: In code behind. Not in the ViewModel though. So <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding}"/> , how do I bind a value that is not in the viewmodel?

Comment: It depends on how and where the value is defined...

Comment: just say the color is defined in the Mainwindow e.g. public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); SolidColorBrush High = (SolidColorBrush) new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#E377C2");}....the value can be changed